# How to fill in AUC of a ROC plot in R?

Tags: r, roc

I have this ROC plot:

```
library(Epi)
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)
data <- aSAH
plot.roc(data$outcome, data$s100b)
```

I want to color the `Area under the curve: 0.7314`.

I tried variations on...

```
x <- seq(1, 0, by = - .001)
polygon(x, roc(data$outcome, data$s100b), 
        col = rgb(.35,0.31,0.61, alpha = 0.4), 
        border = rgb(.35,0.31,0.61, 0.4),
        lwd=2)
```

[image]
... and get the error message: `Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ`.

How can I make the lengths work out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `plot.roc` function from `pROC` has built parameters to enable (`auc.polygon`) and tune (`auc.polygon.col`, `auc.polygon.border`, etc., see `?plot.roc`) the display of the AUC. In your case you could use:

```
plot.roc(data$outcome, data$s100b, 
    auc.polygon = TRUE, 
    auc.polygon.col=rgb(.35,0.31,0.61, alpha = 0.4), 
    auc.polygon.border=rgb(.35,0.31,0.61, 0.4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
library(Epi)
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)
data <- aSAH
res <- plot.roc(data$outcome, data$s100b)
polygon(with(res, cbind(specificities, sensitivities)), 
        col = rgb(.35,0.31,0.61, alpha = 0.4), 
        border = rgb(.35,0.31,0.61, 0.4),
        lwd=2)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is useful, but it only shades from the diagonal up - Not 0.7 of the entire surface, or is it? I may be confused...

Comment: @Toni did you take this answer and try anything yourself? `rbind(with(res, cbind(specificities, sensitivities)), c(0,0))` possibly?