# Polygon in R "stopping" at the diagonal

Tags: r, plot, roc

After getting help on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35539581/4089351), I set out to reproduce the results "manually" and produce an identical ROC curve.

This almost worked, except for two details. One, I can't change the limits of the `y axis` on the plot to the left; and two, the filling of the AUC on the plot to the right stops at the diagonal:

[image]

The code for the left plot comes courtesy of the answers to the prior question, but suppressing all the prior formatting of the data, it comes down to:

```
plot.roc(data$outcome, data$s100b, 
         auc.polygon = TRUE, 
         auc.polygon.col=rgb(.35,0.31,0.61, alpha = 0.4), 
         auc.polygon.border=rgb(.35,0.31,0.61, 0.4))
```

On the right, the code was:

```
plot(rock[,6] ~ rock[,7], xlim = rev(range(rock[,7])), type = 'l') 
polygon(rock[,6] ~ rock[,7], xlim=rev(range(rock[,7])), col = 3)
segments(1,0,0,1, col=6)
```

... and `rock` is a data frame put together as:

```
head(rock)
           cut positive negative tru_pos tru_neg      sens     specif
[1,] 0.0000000      113        0      41       0 1.0000000 0.00000000
[2,] 0.1697713      112        1      40       0 0.9756098 0.00000000
[3,] 0.1767962      107        6      40       5 0.9756098 0.06944444
[4,] 0.1840474      104        9      40       8 0.9756098 0.11111111
[5,] 0.1915268      102       11      40      10 0.9756098 0.13888889
[6,] 0.1992360       93       20      37      16 0.9024390 0.22222222
```

How can I make the green fill the lower triangle below the diagonal? And if at all possible, could I sneak a second quick question about reducing the y axis on the left from (-0.5, 0.5) to (0, 1).

EDIT:

Adding a row of zeros at the end, I generate this:

[image]

Not too bad, but for the vertical blue line on the right margin...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the point (0, 0) in your call to `polygon`.

If you call it on the ROC data, `polygon` will simply close the shape by joining the first and last points of your curve. It has no way to know you want it to go through (0, 0) so you have to specify it explicityl, something like:

```
poly <- rbind(rock[,6:7], c(0,0))
polygon(poly, xlim=rev(range(rock[,7])), col = 3)
```

Comment: With `rbind` or while you're generating `rock`... that' really up to you.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it at first. Yes, no problem, I did add a row of zeros, but notice the extra blue vertical line on the right margin...

Comment: The (0, 0) is NOT part of the ROC curve. I'll update my answer.